# Audio Recording from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, bower, recorder.js

I have downloaded the web audio example master from https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs but when i am opening the html file audio recording is not taking place.How can i use this in my html program to implement audio recording?

Comment: You need to give us more concrete details and specific description of your problem. Did you see any error messages in your browser's console? Did you [check the project for known issues](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues)? It is difficult for us to help when your question is, in essence, "I don't have a code and I have a problem but it's not working".

Comment: i am trying to make a virtual piano.I want to record the notes being played on it.how do i do it?how do i implement recording in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just record the actual notes and timings of the input, and generate an audio file with your piano sounds from that information? It seems strange to record the playback when you already have all that information available to you (assuming you have created the virtual piano).